# Xcode sometimes forget resources

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios4, xcode4

I'm experiencing this huge problem.
I've got one iOS app that I use as base-ground for others. Usually I copy the project in different directories and then overwrite the graphs resources with others with the same name and same sizes in res.

The problem is that sometimes Xcode (both 3 and 4) forget some of them, even if they are present and linked in the resources group. I've noticed also that they are present in the "Copy Bundle Resources" of target. The error happens on device and simulator.

It always happens with images especially the one with different suffix such as: ~ipad,@2x

Some clues:

-deleted all .svn hidden folders

-the image is not referenced in any xib, but only in code

-the name is correct ( I'm aware that simulator isn't case sensitive while the device is)

-the target of the file is set corrctly in itself and also in the "Copy Bundled Resources"

-changing the name of the file (and code, of course) doesn't change this weird behavior

-"touch" the file doesn't change

-clean all target doesn't make any difference

-restore simulator doesn't make any difference

-file isn't localized

-deleting the file and add it again doesn't affect the problem

-Inside the .app package the image is present

Is there a hidden directory or something????or a plist with the referenced resources?

Thanks for the help,
Andrea

Comment: have you checked the full path in the xcode file inspector? Maybe you created a reference to another project and deleted the actual file from that project? I've had some issues copying whole projects and I avoid that. There have also been times when there seems to be a hidden cache of images that isn't getting cleared in xcode.

Comment: Thank you user697562. Yes the path is correct.

Comment: TO make a better clean of the project, I've also deleted also the hidden .svn directory but the problem remains. It's incredible, it seems that the old file remain cached/in memory somewere, I can't believe that change the name of file, deleting it doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!!
I've delete ALL .svn folders inside the main project folder. Open the project, clean targets, restored iphone simulator. Everything seems to be ok.

How to show .svn folders. In terminal write:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

killall Finder
```

To restore the previous config:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE

killall Finder
```

Hope this helps.
Ciao,
Andrea

Comment: wow, this would be an xcode bug then, no? Deleting all svn folders isn't a very good solution tho, other than to figure out the problem. You could also just do "svn export".

Comment: Yes you are right, that is not the best solution, but since I need to keep updated just the base-ground, there is not problem to delete them when I "split" the project coping it in different folders. I totally agree saying that isn't the most productive solution.